# Consultar BD após sair o foco do input e retornar resultados sem dar refresh?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Tenho uma tabela que possui cerca de 30 campos inputs para realizar um lançamento, exemplo:

```
<input type="text" size="8" name="Codigo[]" placeholder="Codigo" maxlength="8" />
<input type="text" size="8" name="Codigo[]" placeholder="Codigo" maxlength="8" />
<input type="text" size="8" name="Codigo[]" placeholder="Codigo" maxlength="8" />
<input type="text" size="8" name="Codigo[]" placeholder="Codigo" maxlength="8" />
```

Ai que vem o problema, eu não sei nada sobre jQuery ou AJAX, e tudo que pesquiso pela internet usa exemplos usando eles, mas não explicam o que cada coisa faz então eu não consigo adaptar para a minha necessidade.
Eu trabalho com PHP onde esse formulário eu recebo em outra página na qual irei gravar os dados no BD, mas antes eu preciso que quando for digitado um código no campo e for dado o foco no próximo campo, ele pesquise no BD o equipamento referente aquele código e retorne o resultado em um campo ao lado, sucessivamente para cada um dos campos, que são exatamente iguais ao do exemplo acima!

Comment: Dà uma olhada nesse site aqui: http://jqapi.com/#p=jQuery.ajax ; É a documentação do jQuery. Pensa em ``Ajax`` como uma requisição HTTP feita por Javascript, só isso. O sevidor só precisa responder os dados que você pedir ao mandar a requisição. Mas aconselho a você estudar jQuery pra valer: http://fabrica.ms.senac.br/2013/06/jquery-um-simples-tutorial-para-iniciantes/

Comment: Obrigado @Daniel, irei sim dar uma lida nesses materiais que você linkou aqui!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode fazer da seguinte forma:

Ao sair do campo manda uma requisição por ajax para uma página php, ela por sua vez busca os dados como necessário e retorna para o ajax, que adiciona os dados na tela como desejar, segue exemplo:

```
    //dispara um evento quando sair do campo
    $(".codigo").blur(function(){
    //envia uma requisição por post passando como parâmetro o codigo digitado.
         $.get("enderço da sua página php?codigo="+$(this).val(), 
         function(dados){
          //dados retornados pelo php adicionados na tela onde desejar
          $(dados).appendTo('body');
       })
    })
```

Tudo que você precisa fazer no php é montar o html com os dados que quer adicionar na tela:

Recebe os dados por `$_GET["codigo"]` -> busca no banco -> monta html -> pronto

O ajax desta forma que eu disse fará a mesma coisa que o navegador faria quando acessamos a página diretamente, retornando todo o html gerado pelo php.

Comment: Obrigado @edson, eu ainda não consegui fazer, me perdoe pela minha ignorância, eu não entendi como eu retorno os dados da página php para esse código ajax que vc usou de exemplo, e depois como pego o resultado e coloco onde eu quiser. no caso onde você escreveu 'body', é uma variável com o resultado obtido pelo php?

Comment: Todos os dados vindos do php vão estar dentro do `dados`, esse "body" é um elemento qualquer na tela, neste caso, o html vindo do php através do dados pode ser inserido em um elemento da tela. Vou tentar criar uma sala de bate papo. 1min

Comment: Okay, estou aguardando!

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/55710/ajax-jonatasm?tab=general

Comment: Parabéns @edson, Me ajudou muito! funcionou Direitinho!